# QCA9377 Unstable WiFi connection on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, atheros

I have a problem with Wi-Fi on a Dell laptop with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac wireless network adapter.
WiFi somewhere every 5-10 minutes just stops receiving and sending data. I can not connect to the router (192.168.1.1) too. If I just reconnect to the hotspot, then the next 5 minutes Wi-Fi is working.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this annoying problem?

*Result of wireless info script :*

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Mar 2019 11:32 EET +0200

Booted last: 13 Mar 2019 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 17:45:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:0839]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e009 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5769 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:32e2 A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6447104  0
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           360448  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    28672  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              778240  1 ath10k_core
dell_laptop            20480  0
cfg80211              622592  4 wl,ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
dell_wmi               16384  0
dell_smbios            24576  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
dell_wmi_descriptor    16384  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,dell_wmi
wmi                    24576  5 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  45056  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.37/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 7017sec preferred_lft 7017sec
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:10   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.37  metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']
nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       952     1  0 10:24 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath10k_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-46-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       59b82a3a-2767-4b9c-a58b-92badc3e0d30
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2,0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d268075f-33da-4964-9b82-ca01910c278f | HUAWEI-B315-69E1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   59b82a3a-2767-4b9c-a58b-92badc3e0d30 | BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.37/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1552476585
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.37
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = zyxel.com
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::1e74:dff:fea3:df73

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 


##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HUAWEI-B315-69E1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HUAWEI-B315-69E1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HUAWEI-B315-69E1
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Riga (based on set time zone)

country LV: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)


##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     00D38A27B7E3C7B97C238FC
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       4.15.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     7F4BDE780A2E9E810538CB1
depends:        ath10k_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_pci
vermagic:       4.15.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac wireless LAN cards.
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     4FA4F8DF5C220FBE3E53039
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_core
vermagic:       4.15.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11 frame datapath (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     555BBBB9D4FCA58A05E7C0D
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       4.15.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     10B87D6D65DDD085D1326C9
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     62FD05DCC5AEEA290640C3D
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
rawmode: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
options iwlwifi swcrypto=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/config.d/config] (644 root)
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi wlp2s0"

grep: /etc/pm/power.d/wireless_power_management_off: Permission denied

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 1802.467199] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [24]: 0x809BF546 0x0040E7E8 0x00426470 0xC0985B3A
[ 1802.467207] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [28]: 0x809B90D8 0x0040E958 0x00000018 0x0042E9E8
[ 1802.467220] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [32]: 0x809B859A 0x0040E9A8 0x0040E9CC 0x00428D74
[ 1802.467228] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [36]: 0x8091D252 0x0040E9C8 0x00000000 0x00000001
[ 1802.467236] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [40]: 0x809EDD7B 0x0040EA78 0x00437544 0x00429428
[ 1802.467243] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [44]: 0x809EB6A6 0x0040EA98 0x00437544 0x00000001
[ 1802.467251] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [48]: 0x80911210 0x0040EAE8 0x00000010 0x004041D0
[ 1802.467259] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [52]: 0x80911154 0x0040EB28 0x00400000 0x00000000
[ 1802.467267] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [56]: 0x8091122D 0x0040EB48 0x00000000 0x00400600
[ 1802.467273] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
[ 1802.467295] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400   5   5   3   3
[ 1802.467316] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800  23  23 260 261
[ 1802.467336] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  10  10  73  74
[ 1802.467357] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000  16  16  17  16
[ 1802.467377] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 5255 5255 133  69
[ 1802.467398] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0   0   0
[ 1802.467419] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00  27  27  27  27
[ 1802.467440] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
[ 1803.352671] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: device successfully recovered
[ 1982.242540] wlp2s0: AP <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> changed bandwidth, new config is 2452 MHz, width 1 (2452/0 MHz)
[ 2001.274565] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2005.048208] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]>
[ 2005.084368] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2005.088337] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2005.092643] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2005.105414] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[ 2005.107983] wlp2s0: associated
[ 3627.828715] wlp2s0: AP <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> changed bandwidth, new config is 2452 MHz, width 2 (2442/0 MHz)
[ 3627.865407] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid 710a848a-3e76-4e4c-83de-ea74afd03074)
[ 3627.865433] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 1028:1810
[ 3627.865439] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[ 3627.866295] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[ 3627.866314] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 544289f7
[ 3627.866320] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[ 3627.868335] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware register dump:
[ 3627.868347] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [00]: 0x05020001 0x000015B3 0x00985B3A 0x00955B31
[ 3627.868355] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [04]: 0x00985B3A 0x00060730 0x00000004 0x00000001
[ 3627.868362] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [08]: 0x00955A00 0x00438830 0x00450888 0x00420970
[ 3627.868370] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[ 3627.868377] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [16]: 0x00952CC4 0x0091080D 0x00000000 0x00000000
[ 3627.868384] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [20]: 0x40985B3A 0x0040E788 0x00400000 0x00421888
[ 3627.868392] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [24]: 0x809BF546 0x0040E7E8 0x00426470 0xC0985B3A
[ 3627.868403] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [28]: 0x809B90D8 0x0040E958 0x00000018 0x0042EA0C
[ 3627.868410] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [32]: 0x809B859A 0x0040E9A8 0x0040E9CC 0x00428D74
[ 3627.868417] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [36]: 0x8091D252 0x0040E9C8 0x00000000 0x00000001
[ 3627.868424] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [40]: 0x809EDD7B 0x0040EA78 0x00437544 0x00429428
[ 3627.868431] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [44]: 0x809EB6A6 0x0040EA98 0x00437544 0x00000001
[ 3627.868438] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [48]: 0x80911210 0x0040EAE8 0x00000010 0x004041D0
[ 3627.868445] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [52]: 0x80911154 0x0040EB28 0x00400000 0x00000000
[ 3627.868452] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [56]: 0x8091122D 0x0040EB48 0x00000000 0x00400600
[ 3627.868458] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
[ 3627.868478] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400   5   5   3   3
[ 3627.868499] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800  14  14 507 508
[ 3627.868519] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  32  32  95  96
[ 3627.868539] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000  11  11  12  11
[ 3627.868558] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 7415 7415 189 125
[ 3627.868578] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0   0   0
[ 3627.868597] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00  29  29  29  29
[ 3627.868617] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
[ 3628.755443] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: device successfully recovered
[ 3807.542243] wlp2s0: AP <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> changed bandwidth, new config is 2452 MHz, width 1 (2452/0 MHz)
[ 3911.400608] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3915.193118] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]>
[ 3915.229028] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 3915.230695] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 3915.238183] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 3915.242594] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'BROSAITE KURITJ SOSEDI' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[ 3915.244871] wlp2s0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Most likely antenna cable detached.

Comment: @Pilot6 on the second system Win10 wifi works without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by changing router settings.

Changed Channel Width from auto to 20MHz.

Original: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414770

Comment: Hello, could you be more specific? I am having the same problem. Do you mean I have to change something in the router that was provided by my ISP? I do not think I can do that

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has problems...or wants the channel width back to auto: Try installing linux kernel 4.19 or up. It fixed my problems....

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/linux-kernel-4-19-released-install-ubuntu/