# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 dropping wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros

I am having a lot of problems with Wifi (wired connection don't have any issues). The strange thing is that happens only on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 x86_64 4.15.0-101-generic computer (I also tried to reinstall and put the 20.04 fresh, but nothing changed), all others have Windows/Android and are not affected.

What happens is that after a while browsing, I lose my internet connection, leaving the icon in the upper right corner with the question mark and getting "err_disconnected_internet", "dns_probe_finished_nxdomain" or "dns_probe_finished_no_internet" from Chrome. To "solve" I need to switch from the 2.4G network to the 5G network (and vice versa), but soon afterwards the problem occurs, often in less than 5 minutes (sometimes more, sometimes less).

I've tried several things, but all without success, I'll leave all of them here:

When viewing the `dmseg -w` command information, I saw that my country code (which is currently Brazil) was apparently changed to IE:

```
[1610.124972] wlp2s0: associated
[1610.125195] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x804c
[1610.125197] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[1610.125200] ath: doing EEPROM country-> regdmn map search
[1610.125202] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3b
[1610.125205] ath: Country alpha2 being used: BR
[1610.125206] ath: Regpair used: 0x3b
[1610.125210] ath: regdomain 0x804c dynamically updated by country IE
[1610.159599] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by ...
```

I tried to change in `/etc/default/crda`, but without success. Afterwards, I tried to disable powersave by changing `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to "2", but also without success.

Note: even after the two changes above, the output of `dmseg -w` remains the same, but `iwconfig` really shows that powersave is disabled.

After that, I tried reinstall netwok-manager, use Google Public DNS, and nothing changed.

After erasing everything and placing 20.04, I thought I had solved the problem, but it come back shortly after.

I managed to get some logs just before the drop:

**journalctl -u NetworkManager --follow**

```
jun 08 00:38:26 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1591587506.4061] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
jun 08 00:38:29 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 NetworkManager[742]: <info>  [1591587509.3816] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

**journalctl --follow:**

```
jun 08 00:39:00 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
jun 08 00:39:00 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
jun 08 00:39:00 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
jun 08 00:39:01 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 CRON[78496]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
jun 08 00:39:01 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 CRON[78497]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
jun 08 00:39:01 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 CRON[78496]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
jun 08 00:39:32 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 systemd-resolved[700]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2804:....
jun 08 00:39:33 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 systemd-resolved[700]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2804:....
```

Here's some outputs:

**iwconfig:**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NAME_5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.785 GHz  Access Point: ...   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:154   Missed beacon:0

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.
```

**lspci | grep -i wireless:**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**/etc/resolv.conf:**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search spo.virtua.com.br
```

Please, I really don't know what else to do

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention something that may be very relevant:

Only on this particular network do I have drops, on any other I have no problems.

**Router Info**

HGJ310 HUMAX

Technology
DOCSIS 3.1

Hardware Version 
1.0

Software Version
BRGCAI 1.0.18

**EDIT 2**

I don't know how much of a coincidence this is, but apparently accessing some specific sites makes the wifi go down faster, like some W3 Schools pages, giving me the following log:

```
Jun 08 02:09:24 lucius-Lenovo-ideapad-320 systemd-resolved [694]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP
```

With some research, I stopped that this is just an alert, and it didn't cause an error in itself...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QCA9377 Unstable WiFi connection on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125262/qca9377-unstable-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I got to see this link before, but the 2.4G network is already at 20MHz and it also has drops, so that doesn't seem to be the problem :/

Comment: Before I had no problem... Only on this Wi-Fi this started to happen (in others I have no problems), I will add this to the question, thanks

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix fair enough, comment cheerfuly deleted. I also have several Atheros chipsets that work very well, and had others in the past that did not. Spotty service on just one network suggests possible congestion upon that channel.

Answer (score 1):

There is a large Q&A here:

- [[Solved] QCA9377 Wireless device not working after upgraded Linux 4.14.85-1](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-qca9377-wireless-device-not-working-after-upgraded-linux-4-14-85-1/68194/20)

After running `dmesg | grep -i firmware` and `dmesg | grep -i ath10k` amongst many other commands, the solution was this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo nmcli networking off
sleep 1
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sleep 1
sudo ip link set wlp2s0 down
sleep 1
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sleep 2
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_core
sleep 2
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
sleep 2
sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up
sleep 1
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
sleep 2
sudo nmcli networking on
sleep 1
exit
```

Even if the script doesn't work for you, read the entire Q&A in case something else does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, all the suggestions from the tbg user did not give me positive results. The wifi works for a few minutes, but stops again later.