# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 unstable connection with ping spikes

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros, ping

Recently I bought a laptop Acer E15 E5-553G-T4TJ and I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

This laptop is equipped with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 as wireless card and many times I face ping spikes and even disconnects.

In regular use, like YouTube, Google Meet, etc, I can't feel this issue, but it is there. I really feel this when I try to play anything (aka League of Legends under Lutris). My ping go over 100ms when playing.

First of all, I tried to buy a new router, but it doesn't work. So I decided to check my latency in terminal, pinging Google.com. For my surprise, I found high ping spikes. Intrigued about that, I tried to ping my router and voilá, I have my ping spikes as well.

This is my ping logs to my router:

```
PING www.mwlogin.net (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=13.2 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=67.6 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=114 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=150 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=4.63 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=3.66 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=23.4 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=55.4 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=43.2 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=73.2 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=102 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=126 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=154 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=4.36 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=5.33 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=85.4 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=149 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=157 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=22.6 ms
64 bytes from _gateway (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=11.2 ms
^C
--- www.mwlogin.net ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19030ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.661/68.308/156.966/56.062 ms
```

With this said, I'm sure the problem isn't in my router nor ISP, but in my PC, probably with drivers.

So I researched a lot to found anything and I found that Qualcomm Atheros wireless cards are really problematic. I found a lot of possible solutions and I've tried many of them. I'll try to link to any I've tried, but I don't remember them all.

I tried:

- Disable hardware encryption, following [this It's FOSS article](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/); I adapted from ath9k to ath10k (I found this on internet as well);
- Fix Avahi-daemon in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/);
- Disabled ipv6 support (https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/);
- Disabled power saving mode on Wireless adaptor
- skip_otp=y on ath10k_core in `/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf`
- Set Reg Domain properly in `/etc/default/crda`
- Disable DHCP (I'm on Static IP right now)
- I tried this solution: [Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 dropping wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248072/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-dropping-wifi)
- I tried to install backports, but did not parse kernel, so I can use `make` command

I think this is all I've done, but I'm not sure.

I noticed that my ping spikes when I'm stressing GPU, so it could be related.

Here are my logs:

`iwconfig`:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Rudah"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 38:6B:1C:7D:3D:D6   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:19   Missed beacon:0
```

`dmesg | grep atk10k`

```
[   15.096274] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   16.450335] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6
[   16.450339] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   16.450954] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 42e41877
[   16.571762] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
[   16.646057] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   16.664790] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.56 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   16.810650] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   32.981113] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[10191.788103] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 0 ar-state 1): 0
[10194.311146] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[14252.126988] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
```

`hwinfo --netcard --wlan --bluetooth | grep -Ei "model\:|driver\:|status\:|cmd\:|file\:|detected\:" | grep -v "Config Status"`

```
  Model: "Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter"
  Driver: "ath10k_pci"
  Device File: wlp2s0
  Link detected: yes
    Driver Status: ath10k_pci is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe ath10k_pci"
  Model: "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller"
  Driver: "r8169"
  Device File: enp1s0f1
  Link detected: no
    Driver Status: r8169 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe r8169"
  Model: "Lite-On Bluetooth Device"
  Driver: "btusb"
    Driver Status: btusb is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe btusb"
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I think that's it.

Please, can someone help me? I have no clue what's wrong! :(

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying many things, I think I solved this issue.

**WARNING:
I don't know if what I've done is correct, but it worked for me.**

First of all you need to download the most recent firmware on [KValo's github](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware) on QCA9377/hw1.0 and copy the content to /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/

```
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377
```

Here is the thing, I tried many times to replace the file `firmware-5.bin` with many versions of firmware with no success. So I identified the version on dmesg

```
dmesg | grep -E 'ath10k_pci .* firmware ver'
```

You may read the version you have installed (WLAN.TF.*).

Now you need find this version on the folders

```
ls -R /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/ | grep '.*WLAN.TF.<here you should fill with your dmesg result>'
```

Once you find the version you're running, you may find the firmware you're running with MD5 checksum

```
md5sum /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/<your firmware location based on previous ls command>
md5sum /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin
md5sum /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

In my case, I was running `firmware-6.bin`, so I copied the latest version of the firmware to this file (which is, for now, WLAN.TF.1.0-00023-QCATFSWPZ-1).

```
cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin.old
cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/WLAN.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00023-QCATFSWPZ-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin
```

**Make sure to match the firmware you're running to the file before copy!
In my case it was firmware-6, but but it could be different to you!**

Again, I don't know if this is correct for any case, but worked for me.
Hope I could help.